# Encrypting multiple files in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

using the following script to encrypt files

```
#!/bin/bash
# crypten - a script to encrypt files using openssl

FNAME=$1

if [[ -z "$FNAME" ]]; then
echo "crypten <name of file>"
echo "  - crypten is a script to encrypt files using des3"
exit;
fi

openssl des3 -salt -in "$FNAME" -out "$FNAME.des3"
```

this only allow one file in and one file out, what i'd like to be able to do is batch encrypt files with a certain extension. ie if I have a folder with 1.text 2.text 3.text 4.text I want to be able to do crypten *.text and it converts all four files to .des3

Comment: I suppose you know that 3DES is considered too weak to provide much security (but it is also approved by the US-NIST under FIPS-140 until 2030, by which time doorknobs will have enough computing power to crack it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the positional arguments; using `$#` to check that at least one was received and `$@` (quoted) to retrieve each one in order.

```
if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "crypten <file1> [ <file2> ... ]"
    echo "  - crypten is a script to encrypt file using des3"
    exit
fi
for FNAME in "$@"; do
    openssl des3 -salt -in "$FNAME" -out "$FNAME.des3"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use the Unix philosophy** - *one tool for one specific task*.
You want encrypt one file, it's ok - you can use your own script for it.
You want to apply script for each file in directory - `xargs` doing it well:

```
ls -1 dir_name/*.text | xargs -d '\n' -i crypten {}
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. This will break for file names that contain newlines.

Comment: That doesn't help. You can't distinguish between newlines that are part of a file name from newlines that separate entries in the output of `ls`.

Comment: @chepner Yep. I give up. My solution don't work for file names that contain new lines.

Comment: Your solution would work using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`. I'm in disagreement of your use of the Unix Philosophy here. This `crypten` script does one thing well, encrypt 1 file. With a little tweaks it can encrypt multiple files but this is not a violation of the unix philosophy. Or cannot `cat`, `tail`, `head`, `sort` and so on to process multiple files at once? I've never seen someone using `find . -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tail`